How to save PDF after cropping from each page of PDF using pdfplumber?
I am using a PDF with multiple pages that has a table on top of each page that I want to get rid of. So I am cropping the PDF after the top table.
What I don't know is how to combine or save it as 1 single PDF after cropping it.
I have tried below:
import pandas as pd
import pdfplumber

path = r"file-tests.pdf"

with pdfplumber.open(path) as pdf:
    pages = pdf.pages
    
    # loop over each page
    for p in pages:
        print(p)

        # this will give us the box dimensions in (x0,yo,x1,y1) format
        bbox_vals = p.find_tables()[0].bbox

        # taking y1 values as to keep/extract the portion of pdf page after 1st table 
        y0_top_table = bbox_vals[3]
        print(y0_top_table)

        # cropping pdf page from left to right and y value taken from above box to bottom of pg
        p.crop((0, y0_top_table, 590, 840))

Output:
<Page:1>
269.64727650000003
<Page:2>
269.64727650000003
<Page:3>
269.64727650000003
<Page:4>
269.64727650000003
<Page:5>
269.64727650000003
<Page:6>
269.64727650000003
<Page:7>
269.64727650000003
<Page:8>
269.64727650000003
<Page:9>
269.64727650000003
<Page:10>
269.64727650000003
<Page:11>
269.64727650000003
<Page:12>
269.64727650000003
<Page:13>
269.64727650000003
<Page:14>
269.64727650000003
<Page:15>
269.64727650000003
<Page:16>
269.64727650000003
<Page:17>
269.64727650000003
<Page:18>
269.64727650000003
<Page:19>
269.64727650000003
<Page:20>
269.64727650000003

How do I append, save these cropped pages into 1 PDF?
Update:
Seems like its not possible to write or save pdf file using pdfplumber as per this discussion link
(Not sure why this question was degraded to negative. Person who do that should also provide the answer or link to where this is already answered).
Update2:
from pdfrw import PdfWriter

output_pdf =  PdfWriter() 

with pdfplumber.open(path) as pdf:
    pages = pdf.pages
    for p in pages:
        print(p)
        bbox_vals = p.find_tables()[0].bbox
        y0_top_table = bbox_vals[3]
        print(y0_top_table)
        cropped_pdf = p.crop((0, y0_top_table, 590, 840))
        print(type(cropped_pdf))
        output_pdf.addpage(cropped_pdf)

output_pdf.write(r"tests_cropped_file.pdf")

Output & Error:
<Page:1>
269.64727650000003
<class 'pdfplumber.page.CroppedPage'>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[219], line 13
     11 cropped_pdf = p.crop((0, y0_top_table, 590, 840))
     12 print(type(cropped_pdf))
---> 13 output_pdf.addpage(cropped_pdf)

File c:\Users\vinee\anaconda3\envs\llma_py_3_12\Lib\site-packages\pdfrw\pdfwriter.py:270, in PdfWriter.addpage(self, page)
    268 def addpage(self, page):
    269     self._trailer = None
--> 270     if page.Type != PdfName.Page:
    271         raise PdfOutputError('Bad /Type:  Expected %s, found %s'
    272                              % (PdfName.Page, page.Type))
    273     inheritable = page.inheritable  # searches for resources

AttributeError: 'CroppedPage' object has no attribute 'Type'

Update 3:
Seems like this issue of cropping pdf and saving was also raised in 2018 but had no solution as per this discussion link.
If anyone knows workaround then pls let me know. Would really Appreciate !!!

The link you posted already answers your question: "No, it is not possible to create/modify a PDF using pdfplumber. It is focused on extracting information from PDFs, rather than creating/modifying them. You may look at tools like pdfrw for write operations on a PDF"

@Cincinnatus Yes this I got to know when no one answered and I kept on researching and made an update for others who may be researching on this as well. Now I am trying with different packages like Pypdf which seems to be more popular in pdf world and if it doesn't work then will try pdfrw. Thanks !!

pdfplumber 0.11.4 pillow 9.5.0
Actually, it is possible to crop and save data as PDF with pdfplumber, but only if you don't need further data extraction.
Let's say, that you want to supply someone with depersonalized medical document for visual reference, no further processing of the data is expected. In this case, you could crop pages and save them as images in PDF like follows (note that in your sample document, personal info is located within the first rectangle on a page):
import pdfplumber

source_path = '.../sample_report.pdf'
destination_path = 'data.pdf'

pdf = pdfplumber.open(source_path)
cropped_pages = []
for page in pdf.pages:
    x0, x1 = 0, page.width
    y0, y1 = page.rects[0]['bottom'], page.height
    cropped_pages.append(page.crop([x0, y0, x1, y1])
                         .to_image(resolution=400)
                         .annotated)

cropped_pages[0].save(destination_path, 
                      save_all=True, 
                      append_images=cropped_pages[1:])

It can be done because page.to_image().annotated is a Pillow Image object, which in turn can be saved as PDF with additional images passed as a append_images parameter (save_all=True is required in this case).

@KJ I don't know English well enough to place punctuation marks freely. And without them, it's hard for me to grasp the subtle nuances of meaning. But I hope that I understand you. Yes, I support your point of view that extracting required data is better then editing PDF. No, I'm not sure if private data are saved in cropped images in this case (maybe I'm missing something about the viewport, but I couldn't extract the original images from the cropped PDF). And sorry, I couldn't understand the message about 2 different sets of results from the 2 different redactions; but I'd like to know it.

@Vitalizzare Actually I would be parsing this saved pdf (after cropping) again using llm. The idea is to get rid of personal information before giving it to third party llm models. Currently I am already parsing pdf report using pdftotext and trying to replace it through llm models. And thanks alot for putting in so much efforts to help me on this. I Really Really appreciate :)

@KJ I think you understood my objective really well. Currently I am parsing pdf report using pdftotext and trying to replace it through llm models as different lab reports have different column tabular setup which cause my extraction code fail at times. So if I am able to get rid of the Personal Information then I can try to apply llm on varying lab report formats. With redact does it make full proof from not getting read by llm models ? Because I read somewhere that llm used by large organization
to readacts documents can also reverse it to the original document without redact.

@KJ Could you please show me some code example where you have saved the readacted pdf report. I did try to redact using PyMupdf & fitz but wasn't sure after these stepsbbox = [150.01,535.95,159.25,549.56]. fitz_pdf[0].add_redact_annot(bbox), fitz_pdf[0].apply_redactions(). fitz_pdf.close(). And I am totally new to handling documents & pdfs in python so please excuse my ignorance. And I would really like to thank you for putting in so much of efforts and trying to understand my problem from my previous & current post on SO and even trying out the weblink and the process there.Thanku

@KJ thanks for the honest opinion on webapp. You are right about the date issue and I have fixed it now. With the name and other personal information will never be in known areas as the lab report can be of varying format but most of them I have seen contains personal information at the top. If trimming can be done from pdftotext  then I will try that. Cropping and saving pdf has its own flaw like the file size increased. LLM took a lot of time to parse and at one spot it read 1.4 value as 14 which is not correct. So definitely need to try readact or trim approach. And thank you again :)

Thanks @KJ I am using poppler through python but I am not sure how to how pass bbox  parameters in python pdftotext.PDF() function to trim/crop/select particular area in pdf. I know about using layout as pdftotext.PDF(physical=True) but not sure how to use (x0,y0,x1,y1) values with the earlier said function.  I will search more on this.
